# Automatic transmission reverse problem

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, accord

Have a 1999 Honda Accord ex 6.0. Auto transmission. My wife was driving the other day on freeway when her radiator blew a hole smoke came threw the dash so she panicked and turned car off and went to put it in N and actually put in reverse going 60mph now when I put it in reverse it just makes a high pitched grinding noise. Is the transmission shot or is there something I can do to fix it. All other gears are fine.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I'd suggest there's serious damage done to the transmission. If there's a grinding sound when you put it into reverse, the reverse idler and/or main gears are probably shot. You won't know exactly until the transmission is torn down. There's not much you're going to be able to do at home to fix it.